# Display Warning if a component is not contained in a specific parent component

Tags: reactjs

SOLUTION: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/compound-components-with-react-hooks

I am creating a  component and I would like to displays a warning only if  or  are not a child of .

I already made a thing to resolve the issue but I am not satisfied, I think this is ugly.

```
export const CardBody = ({ children, isInCard }) => {
  if (!isInCard)
    console.warning('Not in card')
  return <div className="cardbody">{children}</div>
}
export const CardHeader = ({ children, isInCard }) => {
  if (!isInCard)
    console.warning('Not in card')
  return <div className="cardheader">{children}</div>
}
export const CardBodyContainer = ({ children, isInCard }) => {
  if (!isInCard)
    console.warning('Not in card')
  return <div className="cardbodycontainer">{children}</div>
}

export const Card = ({ children }) => {
  if (children.length > 0) {
    children = children.map((child, index) => {
      if (
        [
          CardHeader.displayName,
          CardBody.displayName,
          CardBodyContainer.displayName,
        ].includes(child.type.displayName)
      ) {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          ...child.props,
          key: index,
          isInCard: true,
        });
      }
      return child;
    });
  }

  return <div>{children}</div>
};
```

this is working with:

```
<Card>
  <CardBody/>
</Card>
```

BUT it Doesn't work with:

```
// displays warning even CardBody is in Card
<Card>
  <div>
    <CardBody/>
  </div>
</Card>
```

Comment: If it's possibly deeply-nested the easiest solution might be to wrap the ancestor component in a context, and in the component in question check for the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short explanation

In short, you're only going 1 level deep within the children. You'll have to recursively traverse through the children of children to assign the `isInCard` property.

#### Long explanation

React composes its children like a tree:

```
(2) ["Card", Object]
    0: "Card"
    1: Object
      type: ƒ CardBodyContainer() {}
      key: null
      ref: null
      props: Object
      children: Array(2)
        0: "Body Container"
        1: Object
          type: "div"
          key: null
          ref: null
          props: Object
          children: Array(2)
            0: Object
            1: Object
            _owner: FiberNode
            _store: Object
        _owner: FiberNode
        _store: Object
```

Where `children` may have their own `children` with their own `props`. Therefore, you have to recursively traverse all `children` and conditionally assign them `props`. Unfortunately, you can't assign properties to all children because sometimes those children maybe be an HTMLElement or a string/boolean/number. As such, you can't/shouldn't assign props to non React Elements.

#### Demo

[image: Edit Recursively Map Children]

#### Code

**Example.js**

````
import * as React from "react";

export const CardBody = ({ children, isInCard }) => {
  if (!isInCard) {
    console.error("CardBody was not used within a Card component");
    return <div className="error">Invalid CardBody</div>;
  }
  return <div className="cardbody">{children}</div>;
};
export const CardHeader = ({ children, isInCard }) => {
  if (!isInCard) {
    console.error("CardHeader was not used within a Card component");
    return <div className="error">Invalid CardHeader</div>;
  }
  return <div className="cardheader">{children}</div>;
};

const CardBodyContainerComponent = ({ children }) => (
  <div className="cardbodycontainer">{children}</div>
);

/**
 * A HOC that checks if a Card Component contains an ```isInCard``` property
 *
 * @function withCardCheck
 * @param Component - a React component
 * @param type - a string of the Card component type that was used
 * @returns {ReactElement}
 * @example withCardCheck(Component, "example")
 */
const withCardCheck = (Component, type) => {
  const wrappedComponent = (props) => {
    if (!props.isInCard) {
      console.error(`${type} was not used within a Card component`);
      // throw Error(`${type} was not used within a Card component`);
      return <div className="error">Invalid {type}</div>;
    }

    return <Component {...props} />;
  };

  return wrappedComponent;
};

export const CardBodyContainer = withCardCheck(CardBodyContainerComponent, "CardBodyContainer"
);

/**
 * Checks if the child is a function (React functional component) and
 * conditionally assigns it an ```isInCard``` property
 *
 * @function childContainsCardElements
 * @param child - a React child component
 * @returns {Object} either empty object or { isInCard: true }
 * @example childContainsCardElements(element)
 */
const childContainsCardElements = (child) =>
  typeof child.type === "function" &&
  [
    CardHeader.displayName,
    CardBody.displayName,
    CardBodyContainer.displayName
  ].includes(child.type.displayName)
    ? { isInCard: true }
    : {};

/**
 * Recursively iterates through children
 *
 * @function recursiveMap
 * @returns {ReactElement}
 * @example recursiveMap(children)
 */
const recursiveMap = (children) =>
  React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    // checks if the child is a valid React element
    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) return child;

    // checks if child have their own children
    if (child.props.children) {
      // if so, then conditionally assign it an "isInCard" prop
      child = React.cloneElement(child, {
        ...childContainsCardElements(child),
        children: recursiveMap(child.props.children)
      });
    }

    return child;
  });

export const Card = ({ children }) => <div>{recursiveMap(children)}</div>;
````

**App.js**

```
import { Card, CardHeader, CardBody, CardBodyContainer } from "./Example";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <h2 className="success">Valid</h2>
    <Card>Card</Card>
    <div className="divider" />
    <h2 className="success">Valid</h2>
    <Card>
      Card
      <CardBody>CardBody</CardBody>
    </Card>
    <div className="divider" />
    <h2 className="success">Valid</h2>
    <Card>
      Card
      <CardBodyContainer>
        CardBodyContainer
        <div>
          <CardHeader>CardHeader</CardHeader>
          <div>
            <CardBody>CardBody</CardBody>
          </div>
        </div>
      </CardBodyContainer>
    </Card>
    <div className="divider" />
    <h2 className="error">Error</h2>
    <CardBodyContainer>CardBodyContainer</CardBodyContainer>
    <div className="divider" />
    <h2 className="error">Error</h2>
    <CardBody>Body</CardBody>
    <div className="divider" />
    <h2 className="error">Error</h2>
    <CardHeader>Header</CardHeader>
    <div className="divider" />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

#### Other thoughts

Be careful about using `index` as a `key`. If the children change at all, then this may cause some UI issues.

Also, instead of throwing a warning, I’d recommend bailing out of the recursion by throwing an error. This way, it’s more apparent that a certain structure is expected/enforced and is not optional. If, for whatever reason, you don't want to bail out of the recursion and you want to reduce the `if (!isInCard)` boilerplate, then you can use a [Higher Order Component (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) like `withCardCheck`.